# No cache and Google AdSense performance

Tags: javascript, google-adsense, cache

I'm developing a page where I need to avoid JavaScript caching by browser. I've added this header:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
?>
```

After this, browsers didn't cache more JavaScript sorting out the issue, but in the same time I noticed a drop in Google AdSense RPM.

Then I removed the added code and now Google AdSense RPM is reaching again a good value.

So, how could I avoid JavaScript caching without meddle with AdSense performance?

Comment: In normal circumstances caching of your JavaScript files should not make any difference in AdSense usage. Do you use some custom AdSense wrappers or Google defaults?
Are you sure that all your js code is initializing properly when you activate caching?

Comment: Are you adding these headers to all files, or just the javascript files?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to avoid Javascript caching, which is not very natural, I would try to fetch the 'variable data part' as a JSON using Ajax for example.

If Google can't be sure what your Javascript is all about (since you configuration means it can change each time), then it cannot trust it. Hence, rather than taking a RPM risk, it will take the safe road and give the RPM to other sites it can trust.